# Add column with binary values in R

Tags: r

I would like to add a new column, name it converted. In the converted column I would like to set all customers who have sales >0 to equal 1 and all customers who have 0 sales equal to 0.

I've tried this so far, but it doesn't create a new column.

`converted <- ifelse(DisplayCampEval$sales>0, 1, 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
DisplayCampEval$converted <- ifelse(DisplayCampEval$sales>0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: I will, I have to wait 10 minutes before I can accept!